# Looping through Checkboxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, checkbox

I tried using JavaScript samples that I found here and other places. The problem is that I am using a Table control working at the server, so the JavaScript I was using does not recognizes the checkboxes which are server side as well.  I kept getting the same error message over and over. I got 20 rows with 2 columns each, one for the checkbox and one for a statement that the user has to validate by checking the box before they can submit.  The user has to physically check each box.  If any checkbox is not checked, then I would like to sees a popup message saying they must check all boxes, Else I am doing a redirect to another page, of course all this on the button click event.  This all on Visual Studio 2010, using C#, the back-end is SQL Server.

Here a sample of the JS I was using:

```
function checkCheckBoxes() {
  if (document.frmTest. CheckBox1.checked == false &&
      document.frmTest. CheckBox2.checked == false &&
      document.frmTest. CheckBox3.checked == false &&
      document.frmTest. CheckBox4.checked == false &&
      document.frmTest. CheckBox5.checked == false &&)
  {
    alert ('You must check all the checkboxes!');
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

then,

```
<form onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes();" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name=" CheckBox1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name=" CheckBox2" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name=" CheckBox3" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name=" CheckBox4" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name=" CheckBox5" value="5">
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

But I realized that the checkboxes can't be server control but JavaScript controls. Thanks.

Comment: Are the checkboxes all separate, or are they generated by a data control, like a `Repeater`?

Answer (score 5):

You need something like this

```
var pass = true;

for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) 
{
    if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox')
    {
        if (form.elements[i].checked == false)
        {
            pass = false;
        }
    }
}

if(!pass)
{
    alert ('You must check all the checkboxes!');
}

return pass;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the HTML ID of the checkboxes by using the C# ClientID property. Insert that ID into your Javascript, and you will then be able to select the relevant checkboxes and do whatever you like with them.

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelectorAll to check for any unchecked check boxes. If there are any, throw the error message, else postback.

```
function checkCheckboxes(){
   if(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length > 0){
     alert("all checkboxes must be checked");
     return false;
   } else{
     return true;
   }
}
```

Note: this will only work in Modern browsers Firefox 3.1+, IE8+ (only in IE8 standards mode), and Safari 3.1+